# Isomorphic homotopy groups of universal cover?

Tags: algebraic-topology

In Ralph Cohen's notes on the topology of fiber bundle he says

(1) on pp.167, $BSO(n) \to BO(n)$ is a universal cover thus $\pi_i(BSO(n)) \to \pi_i(BO(n))$ is an isomorphism for $i \geq 2$

(2) on pp.168, $Spin(n) \to SO(n)$ is a universal cover thus $\pi_i(Spin(n)) \to \pi_i(SO(n))$ is an isomorphism for $i\geq 2$

These statements naturally led me to wonder, for any universal cover $\widetilde{X} \to X$ we have $\pi_i(\widetilde{X}) \cong \pi_i(X)$ $\forall i \geq 2$.  But is it really true?

Comment: Yes, it's true.

Comment: This will be in any book where $\pi_i(X)$ are defined. The proof follows from the lifting criterion.

Comment: It's true, and it's not much harder to prove than the fact that covering spaces induce injections on $\pi_1$. If you are comfortable with Hatcher's chapter on covering space theory you can probably prove it.

Comment: Many thanks guys!  The hint below by Tsemo is the key!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Apply the Serre exact sequence since the fibre $F$ is discrete, $\pi_i(F)=1, i\geq 1$, thus  you have isomorphism between $\pi_i(P)$ and $\pi_i(B), i\geq 2$ where $P$ is the total space and $B$ the base space.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibration#Long_exact_sequence_in_homotopy_groups

Comment: Small remark, but you don't mean the Serre exact sequence, right?